# How to animate a listview?

Tags: android, listview, animation

So I've been searching for tutorials on animating a listview,I want to be able to animate items like this when they appear.

https://lh6.ggpht.com/vs5vNvLr_5XS90eJlgyX43NdpYex7zMniAf8DBSAjM1yV4D0TSDAWB2CTK_6z9NK1TGn=h900-rw

Here is my adapter

```
public class PostsAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

    private Context context;
    public List<PostList> postList;
    ViewHolder holder;

    public void add(PostList object,int position) {
        postList.add(position,object);
    }

    public PostsAdapter(Context context) {
        this.context=context;
        postList = new ArrayList<PostList>();
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return postList.size();
    }

    public PostList getItem(int position) {

        return postList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = convertView; 
        if(v == null){
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.posts_list, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder(v);
            v.setTag(holder);
         }else{
            holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
         }

        holder.title.setText(postList.get(position).postHeader);
        holder.user.setText(postList.get(position).user);
        holder.subclass.setText(postList.get(position).subClass.toLowerCase());
        if(postList.get(position).postBody.contains("jpg")||postList.get(position).postBody.contains("jpeg") || postList.get(position).postBody.contains("png") || postList.get(position).postBody.contains("gif")){
            Glide.with(getActivity().getApplicationContext()).load(postList.get(position).postBody).into(holder.image);
            holder.image.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }else{
            holder.image.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

       return v;
    }
 }

 static class ViewHolder{
 TextView user,title,subclass;
 ImageView image;
  ViewHolder(View v){
      user = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.postUser);
      title = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.postTitle1);
      subclass = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.subClass);
      image = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.postsImage);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**twotoasters** has created a library to apply list item animation. You can find this library on Github named **[JazzyListView](https://github.com/twotoasters/JazzyListView)**.

You can also check sample application on [JazzyListView Sample](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.twotoasters.jazzylistview.sample) on Play store.

**JazzyListView**

> JazzyListView is an extension of ListView designed to animate list item views as they become visible. There are a number of pre-built, bundled effects that can be used by setting the effect in code or an XML layout attribute. Also, it is possible to use a custom effect by implementing a JazzyEffect.

This library is very powerful and supports lots of different animations.

[image: JazzyList Item animation]